# UglifyJSPlugin in production mode shows a React development mode warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, uglifyjs

I have an npm package that is a React component that I've built and am hosting on my private npm server.

I have a React web application that downloads this package and uses it on a page.

Both the component and the web application are being built with webpack, using the UglifyJSPlugin.

When running webpack with the production flag, I receive the following warning:

```
warning.js:36Warning: It looks like you're using a minified copy of the development build of React. When deploying React apps to production, make sure to use the production build which skips development warnings and is faster. See [stack won't let me post urls..]fb.me/react-minification for more details.
```

When I remove the UglifyJSPlugin from the web application's webpack config and run webpack with the production flag, this warning doesn't appear.

Any ideas on how to remove the warning when using UglifyJSPlugin in production mode?

Answer (score 0):

As Marko said, use the DefinePlugin like this.

```
{
    entry: "src/main.js",
    output: {
        path: 'dist',
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },  plugins:[
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env':{
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress:{
        warnings: true
      }
    })
  ]
 }
```

Comment: implementing this now. Is there a way to base the value of NODE_ENV based on an environment variable?

Comment: so I tried implementing this in both the component and the web app with no change in results. I also have the NODE_ENV set to production on the build machine.

Comment: The values of process.env default to the environment variables. With the DefinePlugin you can add/overwrite them in code.

Comment: Not sure why this isn't working for you. Are you using JSON.stringify() or just setting the value as a string. If the later you need double quotes like this:
 
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'
    })

Answer (score -2):

You should use the DefinePlugin and set node environment to production.

Comment: Pretty cryptic answer. It would be better if you would show, with code, what you mean.

Comment: It's hard to type an answer on the phone. You can see it here: https://github.com/codaxy/cx-starter-kit/blob/master/config/webpack.prod.js